# Difference between 'storyboard' and 'moodboard'

Tags: terminology, design-process

I was wondering what is the difference between a storyboard and moodboard? I thought storyboads were only for movies and animation but apparently they use them in the ux field. Or do people just call moodboards, storyboards as well?

Answer (score 10):

### Storyboard

A storyboard is used in UX to illustrate a **sequence** or **flow** of events.

- Usually this means a flow of screens (e.g. login, then home page, then create post page, then submit post, etc).
- But storyboards are also used to illustrate behavioral and business flows (e.g. for a restaurant app, a behavioral storyboard might include `I want to go on a dinner date`, `Pull up an app`, `Narrow a search`, `Select a restaurant`, etc).  This  behavioral storyboard can then be used to design an application with a UX.

**Example UX storyboard** (note the sequential flow):

[image: storyboard]

---

### Mood board

A mood board is not used as often in UX.  Unlike storyboards, which are always ordered in narrative or sub-narrative flows, mood boards are only loosely organized.  Mood boards are used to capture and cluster creative ideas very quickly.  These ideas can range over many topics, but may include:

- Actual screenshots and wireframes
- Color palettes
- Creative inspiration (photographs, videos, etc)
- Emotional inputs and outputs
- Comparable and competitive applications
- And many others.

**Example mood board** (note the informal clustering of different topics):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally use moodboards to gather inspirational images, notes, etc. as a part of the very early brainstorming stage. Storyboards are exactly like you said, they are used to convey sequential pieces of information.

For example, I would use a moodboard to collaborate with a client so that we both have an understanding of the direction that the particular design is moving towards. Then I would use a storyboard to demonstrate a potential user's workflow.

I don't think it matters though, so long as you have a process that works for you!